# PHP echo javascript - Not echoing $

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am echoing a javascript block using PHP like this...

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var $lg = $('#mydiv');
        });
";
```

But I am getting the following error message...

```
Notice: Undefined variable: lg
```

When I inspect the source, the line that defines $lg looks like this...

```
var = $('#mydiv');
```

Any ideas why it is happening? Does the $ need escaping?

Comment: Try using `\$` to escape the $ sign

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using double quotes in PHP, variables are interpolated inside strings, for example:

```
$name = "Elias";
echo "My name is $name";
```

This will print `My name is Elias`.

If you want to use `$` inside an string, you must escape it or use single quotes:

```
$name = "Elias";
echo "I love the variable \$name";
echo 'I love the variable $name';
```

Both echos will print `I love the variable $name`

Also, due to the use of double quotes, you are using single quotes to the html inside your string. <s>This is an invalid HTML, though the browser parse it correctly.</s> (Actually it's valid, sorry)

The right way to do it is to use single quotes to your string, or escaping the double quotes:

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
// or
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, when you echo "-delimited strings in PHP then everything starting with `$` is interpreted as a variable.

You need to escape the string like this:

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(\$){
        var \$lg = \$('#mydiv');
    });";
```

To be safe, you should escape all `$`s in the string.

Answer (score 0):

When using double quotes php interpolate variables, so it's trying to evaluate `$lg`, that's why it's not showing on the output.

If you change to single quotes on the echo, it should work.

Or simply escaping `$` with a backslash  (`\`) on a double quotes string.